# Parameter "baseUrl" is required by @Configuration on method when running single class or test from cmd

Tags: maven, parameters, testng

I have little problem with running test from command line in my project. I using Java + TesNG + Maven. When I execute "mvn clean test" from the cmd, everything is ok and all my test cases are running well. Problem appears when I try to run only one class or only one test method f.e. "mvn clean test -Dtest=LoginTest". After that I got this error: "*Parameter 'baseUrl' is required by @Configuration on method openUrlBeforeEachTest but has not been marked @Optional or defined*". It seems that when I try run specific tests, testng.xml file is ignored. Why? I doing something wrong?

Here is my surefire plugin from pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.18.1</version>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
         <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
         <version>2.18.1</version>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <configuration>
      <suiteXmlFiles>
        <suiteXmlFile>src/main/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
      </suiteXmlFiles>
      <systemPropertyVariables>
         <environment>${browser}</environment>
      </systemPropertyVariables>
   </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

testng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
  <suite name="suite" verbose="2">
    <parameter name="baseUrl" value="https://someurl"></parameter>
    <test name="sometest">
        <packages>
            <package name="test.pages" />
        </packages>
    </test>
  </suite>
```

specific test class

```
public class LoginTest extends AbstractPageTest<LoginTest> {

   private LoginPage loginPage;

   @BeforeMethod
   @Parameters({ "baseUrl" })
   public void openUrlBeforeEachTest( String baseUrl) {
       Driver().get(baseUrl);
   }

   @AfterMethod
   @Parameters({ "baseUrl" })
   public void deleteCookiesAfterAllTests( String baseUrl) {
       Driver().manage().deleteAllCookies();
   }

   @Test(priority = 0)
   @Parameters({ "user", "pass" })
   public void login(String user, String pass)  {

       loginPage = new LoginPage(Driver()).get();
       loginPage.login(user, pass);

       Assert.assertEquals(Driver().getTitle(), "The page title");
   }
}
```